# Differential operators on a compact Lie group associated to bracket-generating sets

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-operators, laplacian

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group of dimension $m$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. 
Let $\{X_1,\dots,X_h\}$ be a linearly independent set of $\mathfrak g$. 
Assume that $\{X_1,\dots,X_h\}$ is bracket-generating (i.e. the only subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ containing $\{X_1,\dots,X_h\}$ is $\mathfrak g$).

> **Question:** Is discrete the spectrum of the differential operator on $G$ given by $-(X_1^2+\dots +X_h^2)$? Is $0$ an accumulation point of this spectrum?

I have read that this operator is hypoelliptic and essentially self-adjoint, but I don't know how to use this information.

One can show that the eigenvalue $0$ has infinite multiplicity when $\{X_1,\dots, X_h\}$ is not bracket-generating.
Here is the idea of a proof that I found by myself (it could be wrong! **Update 09.10.2018: it is wrong! See a reason below.**).

Let $\mathfrak h$ be a proper subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ containing $\{X_1,\dots, X_h\}$ and let $H$ be the only connected subgroup of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak h$. 
For each $(\pi,V_\pi)\in\widehat G$ (the unitary dual of $G$), one has the embedding
$$
V_\pi\otimes V_\pi^*\to C^\infty(G),\quad v\otimes \varphi\mapsto f_{v\otimes \varphi}(x):= \varphi(\pi(x)v). 
$$
Moreover, by the Peter-Weyl Theorem, the Hilbert direct sums of these finite-dimensional subspaces is dense in $L^2(G)$. 
For any $\pi\in\widehat G$ and any $v\in V_\pi^H:=\{v\in V_\pi: \pi(h)\cdot v=v\quad\forall \, h\in H\}$, we have that
$$
-(\sum_{j=1}^h X_j^2)\cdot f_{v\otimes \varphi} 
= -\sum_{j=1}^h f_{(\pi(X_j)^2\cdot v)\otimes \varphi} 
=0,
$$
since $\pi(X_j)\cdot v=0$ for all $j$ because $X_j\in\mathfrak h$. Furthermore, the number of $\pi\in \widehat G$ such that $V_\pi^H\neq0$ is infinite since $L^2(G/H)\simeq \oplus_{\pi \in\widehat G} V_\pi^H\otimes V_\pi^*$.

By using the same idea, one can show, when $\{X_1,\dots, X_h\}$ is bracket-generating, that the eigenvalue $0$ in the spectrum of $-X_1^2-\dots-X_h^2$ has multiplicity one. In fact, $\pi(-(X_1^2+\dots+X_h^2))$ has all eigenvalues positive for every $\pi \in\widehat G$ non-trivial.

**Update 09.10.2018:** The proof above works perfectly when $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. However, it is possible that $H$ is dense in $G$, in which case $V_\pi^H=\{0\}$ for all $\pi\in\widehat G$, therefore the eigenvalue $0$ has multiplicity one in the spectrum of $-(X_1^2+\dots+X_h^2)$.

Comment: It's surely going to be true.  I think the sketch would be that hypoellipticity tells you that the heat semigroup $e^{tL}$, where $L = -\sum X_i^2$, maps $L^2$ into $C^\infty$; in particular, into a Sobolev space of sufficiently high order, which is compactly embedded back into $L^2$.  So $e^{tL}$ is a compact self-adjoint operator and has discrete spectrum, thus $L$ has discrete spectrum too.  There will be a spectral gap, i.e. 0 is not an accumulation point, and there's a lot of literature on how to estimate it.

Comment: I am not sure offhand where to find a self-contained proof but if I find one I will let you know.

Comment: (I meant to say $e^{-tL}$ in the first comment.)

Comment: This sounds very promising! I couldn't find a proof or a reference in several articles dealing with such differential operators. I hope you can do it!

Comment: The proof of Theorem 2.4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05702.pdf works for locally subelliptic diffusion operators on compact manifolds, hence for Hormander's type operators on compact Lie groups.